# How can I use RCON on Mac?

Tags: macos, server-administration, source-engine

I'd like to remotely interface with my servers (running CS 1.6, TF2, and CS:S) using RCON while I'm on my Mac. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command line tool will work in your terminal: https://github.com/jimbru/srcds-tools

Usage:

```
./srctool rcon 8.8.8.8 RCONPASS "status"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [Gametracker](http://www.gametracker.com/) offers similar services. They have the games you mentioned and offers a Mac version in addition to a Windows version.

Comment: Gametracker doesn't seem to have any server administration features.

Answer (score 0):

Source Admin Tool is a great cross platform alternative to HLSW.

You can read discussions about it on Allied Mods forum here: https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=289370

Download: https://users.alliedmods.net/~drifter/SAT/

Source: https://github.com/Drifter321/admintool